# SQL Query to match a subset of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pattern-matching

I have a table that looks like:

```
CLASS   VALUE
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       A
2       C
3       B
3       D
4       A
5       C
5       A
```

I have a user-submitted data-set of values that I want to find any classes whose values are a subset of the user-submitted data-set.

For example,

If data-set was `A`, `B`, and `C` then the results would be class `1`, `2`, `4`, and `5`.

If data-set was `A` and `C` the results would be class `2`, `4`, and `5`.

If data-set was `A`, then result would be class `4`.

The platform I am on is SQL Server, but really any SQL-based answer would be best.

Comment: How, exactly, are the user-submitted values formatted?  Is it a flat `VARCHAR` of literally `'A, B, and C'`?  Or is it being passed as a table to a proc?  The query seems simple enough, but we need to know how you're processing the user input.

Comment: Sure! It's passed as a table. So you could use an IN clause, but I am not sure where or how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment `It's passed as a table.` - assuming the table is the variable `@UserInput` with a single column of `Value`, you can use a `WHERE EXISTS` clause to check for the existence of that value in the user-input fields, and pull the `DISTINCT` `Class` values.

```
Select  Distinct Class
From    YourTable   T
Where Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    @UserInput  U
    Where   T.Value = U.Value
)
```

Your SQL syntax will vary, but this should point you in the right direction, syntactically.

A full example of how to implement this would be as follows:

**Creating the User-defined Table Type**

```
Create Type dbo.UserInput As Table
(
    Value   Varchar (10)
)
Go
```

**Creating the Stored Procedure**

```
Create Proc dbo.spGetClassesByUserInput 
(
    @UserInput dbo.UserInput ReadOnly
)
As Begin
    Select  Distinct Class
    From    YourTable   T
    Where Exists
    (
        Select  *
        From    @UserInput  U
        Where   T.Value = U.Value
    )
End
Go
```

**Calling the Stored Procedure with user input**

```
Declare @Input dbo.UserInput
Insert  @Input
Values  ('A'), ('B'), ('C')

Execute dbo.spGetClassesByUserInput @Input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stored procedure an pass the user entry as it as string for ex. A,B,C

```
Create Procedure dbo.GetClasses
@v_UserEntry Varchar(200)
As
Begin
    Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(1000)
    Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(300)

    SET @v_UserEntry= REPLACE(@v_UserEntry,',',''',N''')
    Set @SQLQuery ='Select Class'
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' From TableName'
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' Where Value in (N'''+@v_UserEntry+''')'
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' Group By Class'    
    Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery
End
Go
```

Comment: Just tested this, but there is a syntax error on the Where. I tried it with a "having" instead, but it returned an error...